# Angular Formly: Add class to formly-field based on validation

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I would like to add specific classes to `formly-field` based on whether my question is valid or invalid.  My questions are groups of radios. I'm using [Angular-Formly](http://docs.angular-formly.com/).

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7qORbV2M5MHBG1H3nSaH

My form structure is coming in through JSON so I should probably create a template for questions and in that template set the class based on if the question in invalid or valid...just not sure how.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is acceptable to have the classes on a child element that wraps the field then I would define a global field wrapper by doing the following:

```
angular.module('plunker', [
    'formly',
    'formlyBootstrap','
    ]).run(function(formlyConfig){
        formlyConfig.setWrapper({
            template: '<div ng-class="{ \'invalid\': fc.$invalid,\'valid\': fc.$valid}"><formly-transclude></formly-transclude></div>'
        });
    });
```

Example based on yours: http://plnkr.co/edit/a8LurGdkHEXfqyLPmmVK?p=preview